# Scroll bar goes crazy on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so, i write this code to open and close hide sections, but when i open one of them, the scroll bar goes crazy and do the process twice... Can anyone realize where it's the error? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide the div
    jQuery("#reveal").hide();
    jQuery("#reveal2").hide();
    jQuery("#reveal3").hide();
    jQuery("#boton1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#reveal") .slideToggle();
        jQuery("#reveal2").hide();
        jQuery("#reveal3").hide();

    });
    jQuery("#boton2").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#reveal2") .slideToggle();
        jQuery("#reveal").hide();
        jQuery("#reveal3").hide();

    });
    jQuery("#boton3").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#reveal3") .slideToggle();
        jQuery("#reveal2").hide();
        jQuery("#reveal").hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: There's got to be more to your code. Are you using any other libraries? Produce a demo.

Comment: `html` tag? so add `html` code!

Comment: It was a problem with the navigator cache... there was the error